# What are the pros and cons of clear vs yellow tinted shooting glasses?

Tags: shooting, sunglasses

When shooting it is a good idea to wear eye protection, most ranges and shooting competitions require them.

There are two basic kinds, clear plastic, and amber/yellow tinted ones. From what I have seen the UV protection is identical on both types.

What are the pros and cons of each?

Comment: Yellow help in hazy, foggy environments. Other than that it's mostly personal preference. Some competition rear iris sights would come with multiple color filters you could dial in but I rarely used them - peach, yellow, gray, blue, green, etc. https://www.centra-visier.de/en/products/sights/iris-aperture/sight-18/sight-18-competion/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to article [Benefits of Copper, Orange, Yellow And Brown Lens Tints](https://blog.safetyglassesusa.com/benefits-of-copper-orange-amberyellow-brownbronze-lens-tints/) and from my own experience, but with cycling solar glasses:

> Copper, orange, yellow/amber and brown lens tints make an environment appear brighter and are commonly used in low-light conditions. These lens tints significantly block blue light and enhance contrast and depth perception making them helpful for overcast, hazy and foggy conditions.

Whereas the clear plastic ones are regular eye protection.

So it's not really a pro/con stiuation, in my opinion, but it depends on the circumstances which ones to use.

Comment: Depending on shooting sport various color lenses can help make targets stand out  and be more visible... mostly see it with Skeet, Trap, and Sporting Clays.  Only colored lenses I see with folks shooting IPSC, IDPA, Steel Challenge, etc are darkened for sun protection...

Comment: @Jeroen, Good answer. BTW, I have a question not related to your answer. I really like nature photos in general, and the nature photo in your profile looks great. If possible, would you please tell me whether that nature photo or similar nature photos in BIGGER size are available for the public to view and download ? If yes, where are the links ? Thank you very much.